# Visio, Hyperlink to new tab not working

Tags: microsoft-visio

I've created Hyperlink in visio 2010, linking a shape to a tab within the same visio file. I just havve the sub address filled in. Why does this not work? It doesnt work in visio or internet explorer view.

Ex: in internet explorer view, if I hover over the shape I see the hyperlink symbol but clicking does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Hold down the Control key and click.

If that doesn't work, then your problem is much more sinister, and you'll need to provide more details. For example, what specific steps did you take to create the link?

Answer (score 0):

You will also have to hyperlink the shape you wish to navigate.

To know which object to address, you can refer to SHAPE DATA view.
Object name will appear at top (if you have the view window on top).

Hyperlink to page and also object as shown in this example

[image: MSVisio Hyperlink issue. Solved with object addressing]